# How to generate a range of serial numbers by formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to produce an array of numbers from 1 to n, where n is a value in another cell. So if the cell value is 10, I want to generate an array of the numbers 1 to 10.

I found this resource which appears to answer a similar question:

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/auto-serial-numbering-in-google-sheets/

But I think that it requires you to drag down the fill handle, also I didn't really understand from the resource how to apply this formula to generating n numbers. I want a formula which generates the numbers 1 to n without using the fill handle.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT :
The easiest way to generate an array of sequential number in Google Sheets is the `=Sequence` function.

> Syntax : `SEQUENCE(rows, columns, start, step)`
>   [SEQUENCE function on Google's Help Center](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en)

`=Sequence(A2)`

---

There's a way without dragging a cell with `Arrayformula` :

`=ArrayFormula(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2)))` Where `A2` is the `n` value

[image]

---

There's no incrementation in Google spreadsheet so the only way is to find a build-in counter : the rows/columns.
`ROW()` and `COLUMN()` return the adress of a cell or an array with Arrayformula. Now your case is using a dynamic range, to do so we use `INDIRECT()`

> INDIRECT() returns a cell reference specified by a string.

Using `&` to concatenate the first row number (1) with the `n` value.

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I need it to do. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the answer with a simpler way to generate an array of sequential numbers.

Comment: Whoa, that is indeed an even better solution. Where's the double-accept button?

Comment: you can ask the question a second time, answer it while checking the community wiki box ! But I'm not sure this is necessary  :)